# Check the Type of Flow in Mule

Tags: exception, mule

How to check whether the exception is thrown from main/sub-flow/private flow?
I am doing a generic error handler for mule just I want to check where the exception is originating from.

Answer (score 0):

You can use floConstruct object from exception to get flow name to identify source of exception. You MEL `#[exception.component.flowConstruct.name]` in exception strategy. Please refer following screen shot for details.

[image: Snap shot of mule flow debug]

Update:-

To get flow type you can use same flowConstruct object with MEL

```
`#[exception.component.flowConstruct.statistics.flowConstructType]`
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not I am expecting. I want to get the type of flow.

Comment: If I use the above MEL the only type it is giving is "flow". Irrespective of an exception thrown from flow or subflow or private flow.

Comment: I want to distinguish between flow/private flow/sub-flow.

Comment: anupambhusari answer actually helps you. From this you can simply define some naming conventions for your flows such as starting the name with 'my-app_private_flowthatdoesstuff' or 'my-app_mainflow_anothertask' using the flow construct name and checking with startsWith()

Comment: @Pierre But naming the flow with private/sub is not a good standard right.